# ajax response is showing in console but not in alert box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I was creating a small game for childrens. The game is completed building but the problem am facing is the show the alert boxes when needed. Sometimes it shows sometimes it doesn't. When I pressed inspect element I found that its getting printed on the console but not coming in alert box. Sometimes when I hard reset the browser it shows the alert box when needed. I cleared the browser cache and tried its works sometimes and sometimes not. But its getting printed on the console properly as per my code.

Please someone help me on this issue. I have never faced these kind of issue, its very strange and am tensed.

Below is my jquery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#feed_btn").hide();
    $("#finish_btn").hide();

    $("#start_btn").click(function(){
        $("#start_btn").hide();
        $("#feed_btn").show();

    });
});

function RestartGame()
{
    location.reload();
}

var i=0;

function PerformGame()
{
    i++;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'perform_game.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {'button_clicked': i},
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(data) {

            if(data == "Maximum Clicks Reached. You Lose !") {
                swal({title: "Game Over !", text: data, type: "error"});
                $("#feed_btn").hide();
                $("#finish_btn").show();
            }
            if(data == "Maximum Clicks Reached. You Won !") {
                swal({title: "Wow !",text: data,type: "success"});
                $("#feed_btn").hide();
                $("#finish_btn").show();
            }
            if(data == "Hard Luck ! One or Some animal(s) died.") {
                swal({title: "Dead !",text: data,type: "warning"});
            }
               if(data == "Farmer Died ! You Lose !"){
                    swal({title: "Game Over !", text: data, type: "error"});
                    $("#feed_btn").hide();
                    $("#finish_btn").show();
               }

            }
    });
}   
</script>
```

Below is my php code:

```
foreach($_SESSION['animal_life'] as $key => $value)
{
    if ($value == '0') {
        if ($key == 'Farmer'){
            $msg = "Farmer Died ! You Lose !";
            unset($_SESSION['animals']);
            unset($_SESSION['animal_life']);
            unset($_SESSION['final_result']);
            break;
        }

        $search_animal = array_search($key, $_SESSION['animals']);
        unset($_SESSION['animals'][$search_animal]);
    }
    $check_animals_left = count($_SESSION['animals']);
    if($check_animals_left < $count_total_animals) {
        $msg = "Hard Luck ! One or Some animal(s) died.";
    }
}

if ($no_of_times_button_clicked == '50') {
    $counter = 0;
    if (in_array('Farmer', $_SESSION['animals'])) {
        $counter++;
    }

    if (in_array('Cow1', $_SESSION['animals']) || in_array('Cow2', $_SESSION['animals'])) {
        $counter++;
    }

    if (in_array('Bunny1', $_SESSION['animals']) || in_array('Bunny2', $_SESSION['animals']) || in_array('Bunny3', $_SESSION['animals']) || in_array('Bunny4', $_SESSION['animals']))
    {
        $counter++;
    }

    if ($counter == 3)
    {
        $msg = "Maximum Clicks Reached. You Won !";
        unset($_SESSION['animals']);
        unset($_SESSION['animal_life']);
        unset($_SESSION['final_result']);
    } else {
        $msg = "Maximum Clicks Reached. You Lose !";
        unset($_SESSION['animals']);
        unset($_SESSION['animal_life']);
        unset($_SESSION['final_result']);
    }
}

if ($msg) {
    echo json_encode($msg);     
}
}
```

Comment: Just for testing purposes - replace sweetalert (swal) with native js alert and see if error persist.

Comment: @MrAleister yeah same happened with regular alert boxes also. I hard refreshed the browser it worked yesterday and again it showing the problem today. This time I cleared cache and hard refreshed the browser and still the problem persists. I used async:False in ajax but no success for me.

Comment: can you show the responce of ajax request?

Comment: Other thing is - your **if** statements relies on long/complex string comparison, thus are prone to typos. Try to simplify response and conditions (use codes like 'ALL_OK', 'ANIMAL_DEAD'), and keep long strings in alert code only.

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar You mean to say the response I am getting in console which I am expected to get in a alert box ?

Comment: What you get in console or network tab.

Comment: @Snehasis Do not use sentence in `IF conditions`. Bcoz some times your response may have `whitespaces` or `blank lines`. It will not appear in console. But it will effect your `IF statement`. The best way is get data in `JSON` format and `parse` it, Then you can access data as `object`..

Like, (PHP)

`echo "{\"status\":\"0\",\"msg\":\"faild\"}"`;

JS 

`var data = JSON.parse(response);

if(data["status"] == "0"){
//do something
}
`

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar  "Hard Luck ! One or Some animal(s) died."Array
(
    [Farmer] => 7
    [Cow1] => 9
    [Cow2] => 7
    [Bunny1] => 0
    [Bunny2] => 8
    [Bunny3] => 2
    [Bunny4] => 6
)
Array
(
    [0] => Farmer
    [1] => Cow1
    [2] => Cow2
    [4] => Bunny2
    [5] => Bunny3
    [6] => Bunny4
)
This is the response I am getting where the array are from print_r and the sentence which is shown is exactly what I am expecting in alert box

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar My last alert is working fine and its showing in alert box. The one which I have used to show the game win or loss when maximum clicks reached. This is very strange doesn't know what actually is happening. The working code suddenly stopped working. :(

Comment: Change these strings to something simpler for now - like numbers. Like Banujan Balendrakumar and myself are trying to explain you are most likely have some whitespace/typo somewhere

Comment: @Snehasis I faced this problem few years ago. My fault was the `whitespace`. It means a new empty line in response, But it didn't appear in console. it will be marked as '\n' but will not appear.

Comment: Have teamviewer?

Comment: Yes I have the latest version. Or can try AnyDesk !

Comment: Can I see? How can I reach you privately?

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar Let me try to change the long sentence as MrAleistr said...if the problem still stays then I will share you my id and password for Anydesk or TeamViewer !

Comment: Good! you can reach me via, facebook `https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=Balendrakumar%20Banujan`

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar I changed and checked all typos/whitespaces.. still the same error not a single alert is showing and the last alert is only working when the game is over.

Comment: @MrAleister i did as you said to skip long sentences. But still no result. As my last alert is working so I dont find their is a error of whitespaces/long-sentences. As the same code was working some hours ago after hard refresh and now its not working at all.

Comment: @Snehasis - it's really weird. If you put console.log just before each **if** with corresponding condition what do you see?  For example: `console.log("Hard Luck ! One or Some animal(s) died.", data == "Hard Luck ! One or Some animal(s) died.")`

Comment: @MrAleister Sorry, I didn't get you...could you please write down some lines of code such that I will understand what exactly you want to see ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please add this debug:

```
console.log('data is: ',data)
console.log('data == Maximum Clicks Reached. You Lose !',data == "Maximum Clicks Reached. You Lose !")
if(data == "Maximum Clicks Reached. You Lose !") {
    swal({title: "Game Over !", text: data, type: "error"});
    $("#feed_btn").hide();
    $("#finish_btn").show();
}
console.log('data == Maximum Clicks Reached. You Won',data == "Maximum Clicks Reached. You Won !")
if(data == "Maximum Clicks Reached. You Won !") {
    swal({title: "Wow !",text: data,type: "success"});
    $("#feed_btn").hide();
    $("#finish_btn").show();
}
console.log('data == Hard Luck ! One or Some animal(s) died.',data == "Hard Luck ! One or Some animal(s) died.")
if(data == "Hard Luck ! One or Some animal(s) died.") {
    swal({title: "Dead !",text: data,type: "warning"});
}
console.log('data == Farmer Died ! You Lose !',data == "Farmer Died ! You Lose !")
   if(data == "Farmer Died ! You Lose !"){
        swal({title: "Game Over !", text: data, type: "error"});
        $("#feed_btn").hide();
        $("#finish_btn").show();
   }

}
```

Comment: success: function(data) {
          console.log('data is: ',data);
          console.log('data == MAX_CLICK_LOSE',data=="MAX_CLICK_LOSE");
                       if(data == "MAX_CLICK_LOSE")
                       {
                        swal({title: "Game Over !", text: "Maximum Clicks Reached. You Lose !", type: "error"});
                        $("#feed_btn").hide();
      $("#finish_btn").show();
                       }

Comment: I have tried as you asked. and still the same error. "HARD_LUCK_DIED"Array
(
    [Farmer] => 14
    [Cow1] => 2
    [Cow2] => 2
    [Bunny1] => 1
    [Bunny2] => 0
    [Bunny3] => 6
    [Bunny4] => 8
)
Array
(
    [0] => Farmer
    [1] => Cow1
    [2] => Cow2
    [3] => Bunny1
    [5] => Bunny3
    [6] => Bunny4
)      that is the above response I am getting in console

Comment: Where are you getting this `Array ( [Farmer] => 14 [Cow1] => 2 [Cow2] => 2 [Bunny1] => 1 [Bunny2] => 0 [Bunny3] => 6 [Bunny4] => 8 ) Array ( [0] => Farmer [1] => Cow1 [2] => Cow2 [3] => Bunny1 [5] => Bunny3 [6] => Bunny4 )` from ? console.log ?

Comment: As you can see I have used Print_r at last in my php page. that is printing this array

Comment: Could you please share your latest code? I see rather big changes and your last comment suggest you have only one condition now.

Comment: @Snehasis - well, that's your bug. Remove that print_r - it's output is being added to http response

Comment: MrAleister: yeah let me check and come back to you in some minutes... let me remove that Print_r

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183951/discussion-between-mraleister-and-snehasis).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'perform_game.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {'button_clicked': i},
    dataType: 'json',
    async:false

    success: function(data) {

        if(data == "Maximum Clicks Reached. You Lose !") {
            swal({title: "Game Over !", text: data, type: "error"});
            $("#feed_btn").hide();
            $("#finish_btn").show();
        }
        if(data == "Maximum Clicks Reached. You Won !") {
            swal({title: "Wow !",text: data,type: "success"});
            $("#feed_btn").hide();
            $("#finish_btn").show();
        }
        if(data == "Hard Luck ! One or Some animal(s) died.") {
            swal({title: "Dead !",text: data,type: "warning"});
        }
           if(data == "Farmer Died ! You Lose !"){
                swal({title: "Game Over !", text: data, type: "error"});
                $("#feed_btn").hide();
                $("#finish_btn").show();
           }

        }
});
```

Comment: How can you say, This is the solution? Explain your code

Comment: @shaghayegh sheykholeslami: What you have changed ? its looks same as my code.

Comment: `async:false` ? He is using `success` callback  - why would you need `async:false` ?

Comment: when you use async:false your browser locked and waite for your response so for this reasone when you use console.log() or run your console you could see or run your success result.

Comment: @shaghayeghsheykholeslami I have used you code... But no positive result yet... :(

Comment: @shaghayeghsheykholeslami - it's not necessary when you are using it (console.log) in the callback function